# How do the various criteria affect the outcome?

Tags: math, statistics

I have 4 projects (Alfa,Beta,Gamma,Delta). The projects are rank from 1 to 4 based on personal feelings. Afterwards, the projects are evaluated based on 6 criteria (C1-C6).

[image]

What is the significance index of each criterion (how important was each criterion in the projects evaluation based on personal feeling)? What statistic can be used to figure it out? This is probably not multiple nonlinear regression because the order of the criteria is not important in my case but in regression is.

Comment: I don't understand the sentence *"This is probably not multiple nonlinear regression because the order of the criteria is not important in my case but in regression is."*

Comment: You can try to use linear regression and it might work. Imagine that "rank" is a weighted sum of C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6. Then all you want to do is find the weights. A linear regression is the perfect tool for that.

Comment: The main issue here is that you will likely "overfit" your data; you have more columns (6) than rows (4), so there is certainly more than one way to find a model that produces these ranks.

Comment: Without running any algorithm, I can see with my eyes that the weighted sum `(C1+C3)` produces the values Alfa->10, Beta->8, Gamma->7, Delta->5, which is enough to rank Alfa,Beta,Gamma,Delta in this order. The different weighted sum`(C1 + C6 + 0.6 C2)` works as well: it produces the values Alfa->11.2, Beta->10.6, Gamma->6.0, Delta->5.8.

Comment: Re1. while answering you I thought the topic and have to withdraw the sentence. Thank ou
Re2. The rank is not directly correlated to the criteria -->
I pickup 5 best projects from my portfolio because I feel these are the best one. Then I try to understand what drove my decision that is why I select some evaluation criteria and assess the same project criterion by criterion. Now I have to "calibrate" the weights of my criteria, to fit the previously created rank.

Comment: In other words, I have to "find" such weights for every criterion to meet the rank no. of each project. The criteria are not dependent on each other. It could be: cost, time, alignment with business strategy. All the criteria will be expressed in values from 1 to 5.

Comment: if we apply simply the weighted sum it can "do a job" for the first project but not necessarily for the next one.

Comment: I don't really understand. I found a weighted sum (C1+C3) which works to get the four projects in the correct order?

Comment: Absolutely but I'm looking for a way that will allow me to "find" the weights without computing in my head. The amount of data will be much bigger. I need an algorithm.

Comment: I suggest just linear regression ? Trying to express the rank as a weighted sum of the 6 coefficients. Or better, replace the ranks by `100 - 10*rank` or something similar; otherwise the weights are going to be mostly negative (because 1 is smaller than 2, but rank 1 is better than rank 2)

Comment: I'll make some computations and go back. Thank you, Stef.
BTW. why linear regression should be in favour of the nonlinear one?

Comment: Because linear is much much more simple than nonlinear, so we only use nonlinear when linear doesn't work.